# Refreshing GUI in WinForms faster

Tags: c#, winforms

When I move scrollbar, my application fires an event that refresh some controls on the screen. The problem is that refreshing is very slow. I added `DoEvents` method to this event, works really better, but sometimes for processing audio (latency less than 100ms, full screen repaint) it is not enough.

Can I somehow speed up refreshing UI? I found something like this: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?315416-Ok-noobies-DoEvents-is-slow!!!-Here-s-are-faster-methods

But it looks complicated. Is any easier method to achieve this?

Comment: I have heard using OPENGL or DIRECTX works in case of high screen refresh rates....

Comment: Before adding DoEvent or using any other solutions you might try to find out what is causing the slow refresh. You'll need to give more information if you want us to help you with that.

Comment: Simple: each block of audio I play (block size is like 50-75ms) it fires an event which calls gui control to repaint. W/o do events it works horribly slow, with DoEvents its alot better. My repaint function is very fast I think.

Comment: If you are using DoEvents to repaint your UI, I would think you are not threading these other processes and sending notifications back to the main application. That seems like it is likely the biggest issue. Are you threading or using a background worker?

Comment: I thread these other tasks to do. NAudio start new thread to get samples from WaveProvider, then WaveProvider run delegate in GUI thread to change visual cursor position. W/o do events in this delegate, my control refresh very slow.